# Can't Connect To API Resource

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure

I created a React Front end that makes an axios post request to my api. The code coming from the front end is called after a user has successfully logged in. After the user logs in successfully an auth token is sent via a cookie, and that cookie is used to verify if the user is an admin and is able to access the api resource /api/v1/orders. This works when I am in a local environment, but after I uploaded this to the cloud I get this error:

```
<MY_API>/api/v1/orders:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Adminpage.js:31 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:62)
```

REACT FRONT END

Adminpage.js

```
const loadOrders = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "<MY_API>/api/v1/orders",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log(res.data.data.orders);
      setOrderData([...res.data.data.orders]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

NODEJS BACK-END

orderRoutes.js

```
router
  .route('/')
  .get(
    // Only admins can access this route
    authController.requireSignin,
    authController.isAdmin,
    orderController.getAllOrders
  )
  .post(orderController.addOrder);
```

authController.js

```
exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ['HS256'], // added later
  requestProperty: 'auth', // Decodes the token and assigns to auth object in request object
  getToken: function (req) {
    if (req.cookies.Authorization) {
      return req.cookies.Authorization;
    }
    return null;
  },
});

exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  // If users role specified in the req.auth object is not admin, an error is passed to the global error handler otherwise, is able to go to the next function
  if (req.auth.role !== "admin") {
    return next(
      new ApiError(undefined, 403, "User is not authorized for access!")
    );
  }
  next();
};
```

My front end React code is hosted on AWS and my back end Nodejs is hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CORS issue. Have you enabled CORS in the app service that hosts your API? https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript.md

Comment: can you give me more details of your azure deployment? Have you deployed the API app to an App service or Virtual Machine? are you accessing it through APIM or just hitting the app service directly?

Comment: I deployed it through App Service and just hitting it directly.

Comment: My advice would be to first check to see if this is an issue with your authentication mechanism in your react app or if this is an issue with the app service. To check this, create and expose an unauthenticated api endpoint (a good one would be /api/health) where you just return a 200 status code of success. Redeploy your app with this new endpoint and verify if the returns a 200 or 500 status. If it is a 200 then there is an issue with your authentication (check for hard coded values). But if you  still get a 500 for the api/health endpoint, then its your app service.